# Skobbler Maps - Stop rotation during navigation

Tags: android, rotation, skmaps

I am calculating a route using `SKRouteManager` as follows:

```
route.setStartCoordinate(origCoords);
route.setDestinationCoordinate(destCoords);
route.setNoOfRoutes(1);
route.setRouteMode(SKRouteSettings.SKRouteMode.BICYCLE_FASTEST);
route.setRouteExposed(true);
SKRouteManager.getInstance().setRouteListener(thisActivity);
SKRouteManager.getInstance().calculateRoute(route);
```

I am then implementing the `onAllRoutesCompleted()` callback to initiate turn by turn navigation:

```
public void onAllRoutesCompleted() {
    SKNavigationSettings navigationSettings = new SKNavigationSettings();
    navigationSettings.setNavigationType(SKNavigationSettings.SKNavigationType.SIMULATION);

    SKNavigationManager navigationManager = SKNavigationManager.getInstance();
    navigationManager.setMapView(mapView);
    navigationManager.setNavigationListener(this);
    navigationManager.startNavigation(navigationSettings);
}
```

My problem is that it now automatically rotates the map toward the direction of travel - but I want the map to always point north (unless the user chooses otherwise).

**How can I stop the rotation changing due to turn-by-turn navigation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the map's follow mode via [setFollowerMode](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.5.1/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSettings.html#setFollowerMode(com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKMapSettings.SKMapFollowerMode)).
If you want to just follow the user position, but not to rotate the map, set it to POSITION, something like:

```
mapView.getMapSettings().setFollowerMode(SKMapFollowerMode.POSITION);
```